# Find new coordinates of an SVG Element using Group BBOX

Tags: svg, coordinates

How can I get the new size and coordinate properties of an image element so the parent group container BBOX will supposed to change to new target values.

Here's my SVG:

```
<svg width="500"height ="500" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <g id="my_grp">
    <image width="350" height="150" transform="translate(100 100) rotate(35 175 75)" href="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150"></image>
  </g>
</svg>
```

From that example I got the initial bounding box of "my_grp" using `document.getElementById('my_grp').getBBox()` which is:

```
[object SVGRect] {
  height: 323.62457275390625,
  width: 372.73968505859375,
  x: 88.63015747070312,
  y: 13.18772029876709
}
```

I want to resize my_grp box by 30% and move it to (30, 40) coordinates. How can I change the image properties to achieve it?

You may check https://jsfiddle.net/ybjL0zmt/.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can get the help of the [SVGMatrix](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/coords.html#InterfaceSVGMatrix) interface to compute the neccessary transformation. Starting with the identity matrix, you then **move the coordinate system around** to draw the group content into:

```js
const group = document.querySelector('#my_grp');
const bbox = group.getBBox();
// initialize an identity matrix
const matrix = document.querySelector('svg').createSVGMatrix();

const {a, b, c, d, e, f} = matrix
    .translate(30, 40)
    .scale(0.7)
    .translate(-bbox.x, -bbox.y);

const transform = 'matrix(' + [a, b, c, d, e, f].join(',') + ')';
group.setAttribute('transform', transform);
```

```html
<svg width="500"height ="500" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <path d="M30 150V40H200" style="fill:none;stroke:black;stroke-dasharray:5 5" />
  <g id="my_grp">
    <image width="350" height="150" transform="translate(100 100) rotate(35 175 75)" href="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150"></image>
  </g>
</svg>
```